# Swift: Change ViewController after Authentication from RESTful API

Tags: ios, swift, rest, authentication, swift2

I have a rails api set up and one test user. I can login/logout view the api.

I have a tab app set up, and I have a LoginViewController set up to authenticate into that. My view controller (basically) looks like the below code. This **doesnt work**. However, the second block of code **does work**

I am guessing I am calling something wrong.. The first block executes and then crashes with a *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueuewaitUntilAllTasksAreFinished].. I've been spinning my wheels for hours.. tried looking into segues.. etc. Anything would help!!!

```
//DOES NOT WORK //

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

@IBAction func Login(sender: AnyObject) {
    func switchToTabs() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController

    }

    let authCall = PostData()
    var authToken = ""
    authCall.email = email.text!
    authCall.password = password.text!
    authCall.forData { jsonString in
        authToken = jsonString
        if(authToken != "") {
            switchToTabs()
        }
    }
}



// SAME CLASS THAT DOES WORK//

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

@IBAction func Login(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController


}
```

My question is, why can I seemingly navigate to a new view when I don't use my api, but when I do receive my auth token.. I can't log in.

Please excuse the ugly code.. this is my first day with swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you every do anything that changed something about the UI inside of a closure or anything that could even possibly be off the main queue, enclose it in this statement.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //the code that handles UI
}
```

This includes all code that segues inside a closure like the one you have

```
authCall.forData { jsonString in
    authToken = jsonString
    if(authToken != "") {
        switchToTabs()
    }
}
```

If you write it like so it would work

```
 authCall.forData { 
    jsonString in
    authToken = jsonString
    if(authToken != "") {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            switchToTabs()
        }
    }
}
```

then call your segue in `switchToTabs()`

If you arn't sure what queue you are on, it won't hurt to do it. As you become more familiar with scenarios that take you off the main queue, you will realize when to use it. Anytime you are in a closure and dealing with UI its a safe bet that you could leave. Obviously anything asynchronous would cause it as well. Just place your `performSegueWithIdentifier` inside of it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a segue on the storyboard from the view controller attatched to LoginViewController, then you click the segue you can give it an identifier. Then you just call performSegueWithIdentifier("identifierName", sender: nil) and none of the other code in switchToTabs() is necessary.

If you want to continue down the route you are taking to summon the View Controller, then I think what you are missing is these lines.

Use this below your class outside of it.

```
private extension UIStoryboard {
    class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

    class func tabBarController() -> UITabBarController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as? UITabBarController
    }
}
```

Then change your switchToTabs() function out for this

```
func switchToTabs() {
    let tabBarController = UIStoryboard.tabBarController()
    view.addSubview(tabBarController!.view)

    //line below can be altered for different frames
    //tabBarController!.frame = self.frame

    addChildViewController(tabBarController!)
    tabBarController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    //line below is another thing worth looking into but doesn't really correlate with this
    //self.navigationController!.pushViewController(tabBarController!, animated: true)
}
```

I added in a couple comments for you to look into if you like. I believe this will do the job, but keep in mind that the direction you are headed doesn't remove the previous screen from memory. It is technically still sitting behind your new screen. I wouldn't ever recommend this for what you are trying to do, but it might not hurt if you are building something simplistic.

Comment: so i'm calling the login controller from AppDelegate much the same way.. is there a way to segue into the loginVC always at first? or should I keep calling the LoginVC the same and just change this segue. Thanks so much for your help btw..

Comment: seems preformSegueWithIdentifier still fails in the same way... >.<

Comment: the self.navigationController!.pushViewController(tabBarController!, animated: true) line is the programmatic way of doing it I believe without segues, but I never used that method. Be sure that your completion closure is actually being called. [apple segue documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html) The segue must come from the ViewController associated with the class calling it and the identifier String must me identical. One capital letter difference and it won't work.

Comment: I'm still getting the same errors when using preformSegueWithIdentifier. It crashes with the same *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished]